# Use Azure AD B2C for Sign In and MFA then switch to legacy authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

Please bear with me, security is way out of my wheelhouse and I'm just getting up to speed on Azure AD, so I may get some of these terms wrong.

We have an older ASP.NET app with custom identity management that I did not write. I know we're using OWIN Authentication and I'm fairly certain that the dev grabbed the underlying Microsoft code for ASP.NET Identity and customized it for some specific use cases.

I have been tasked with implementing MFA on this app and one of the likely candidates is Azure AD B2C. I'm concerned that I would have to scrap the existing customized identity management because the authentication would obviously be handled by Azure AD, which would replace the OWIN cookie, etc. The demos I've seen all seem to imply this, but does that have to be the case?

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Azure AD B2C to handle MFA and authentication, then just pass off the returned claims in the token to sign in using my existing strategy.

Other vendors appear to be more in line with this. Duo, for example, lets you do your existing sign-in and just returns the result of the second factor authorization.

I would appreciate any feedback or alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> scrap the existing customized identity management because the authentication

I would recommend a lift and shift of the app to the latest version of .Net Core and use the new framework which handles a large chunk of the orchestration instead of the *by hand* of what had to be done using OWIN.

But if you want to keep with OWIN, yes that is possible using Microsoft.Identity.Web

See [v2.0 · AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web Wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/v2.0#owin)

for more information.